# "sudo stop" hanging after several successful stop/start in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, init, upstart

My Ubuntu version is 13.04.
I create a init conf "sbs.conf" in /etc/init/ and its contents follows:

```
description "Upstart file for a sbs"
env USER=root
env HOME=/home/ubuntu/sbs

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [016]

respawn
expect daemon

pre-start script
  rm -f ${HOME}/RUNNING_PID
end script

exec start-stop-daemon \
--pidfile ${HOME}/RUNNING_PID --chuid $USER:$GROUP \
--exec ${HOME}/start --background --start
```

I can use **"sudo stop sbs"** and **"sudo start sbs"** to stop/start it, after machine started.

But, running **"sudo stop sbs"** failed, it was hanging, after executing several stop/start operations successfully.

BTW, there is an interesting thing:

When it works, I can use auto-completion to complete **sbs** after I typed **"sudo stop"**.
After hanging, auto-completion didn't shows **sbs** any more.

It seems that the **"sbs"** is not a job any more?

Comment: You might get more help with this on askubuntu.com or superuser.com.

Answer (score 0):

Change to this, it works.

```
description "Upstart file for a sbs"
env USER=root
env HOME=/home/ubuntu/sbs

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [016]

respawn
#expect daemon

pre-start script
  rm -f ${HOME}/RUNNING_PID
end script

script
  chdir ${HOME}
  /bin/bash ${HOME}/start
end script
```